# How to add roles in images of product with mysql database?

Tags: magento2, database, product-images, media-images

Is it possible insert not update (update is simple) image roles (base, small , thumnail) in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table if in the table missing attribute row for the products images

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to insert new rows in the catalog_product_entity_varchar table for the product image attributes if they are missing.

You can achieve this by creating a custom script or module that queries the product collection and checks if the catalog_product_entity_varchar table has an entry for the base_image, small_image, and thumbnail attributes. If any of these attributes are missing, you can use the following code to insert new rows:

```
    // Load product collection
    $products = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    $products->load();

    // Loop through products and check if image attributes are set
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $storeId = $product->getStoreId();

        // Check if base_image attribute is set
        $baseImageAttr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('base_image');
        if (!$baseImageAttr->getFrontend()->getValue($product)) {
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery('path/to/image.jpg', array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
        }
    }
```

This code checks if the base_image attribute is set for each product and if it's not, it adds the image to the media gallery and sets the image, small_image, and thumbnail roles for the image.

Note: It's recommended to use a module or custom script for this rather than directly inserting records in the database table, as direct database manipulation can be risky and cause issues.